# When Java Runtime loads the jars(objects) into memory?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, classloader, heap-memory

I have a simple Java application say it prints "Hello World" nothing more than that. I kept 4 new jars(not related to Hello World print) in my class path. Does all these jars getting loaded into memory when I run my Hello World application? When these jars get loaded into JVM and when it will get unloaded?. Does it depend on OS or Java virtual machine type? . How much memory Java run-time takes without any application code, just loading the JRE. Basically I want to understand the JVM memory loading process step by step.

Comment: Why is this "(objects)" in the title? jars are not objects, so what exactly are you interested in?

Comment: The answer to this question likely depends on which JVM you are using. Can you clarify this?

Comment: *"I want to understand the JVM memory loading process step by step"* - depends on what you mean by "JVM memory loading". Anyway, the question, as it currently asked, is too broad. Try to limit it to a specific problem and avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once.

Comment: @PiRocks , I am using Hot Spot JVM

Comment: @apangin, I am talking about the Objects inside the jar

Comment: jar contains *files*, not *objects*. Specifically, *class files* and *resources*. How Java classes are loaded is thoroughly specified in [JLS Chapter 12](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-12.html) and [JVMS Chapter 5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se14/html/jvms-5.html).